# sharepoint 2013 accessing with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, https, sharepoint-2013, unc

I've been working with SharePoint 2010 with no problem using  VBA and accessing the folders via a simple path
\root\site\folder , structure.
I've just had a new site created in SharePoint 2013, and using the same technique doesn't work.
I can add a network location in this format
https://server/sites/Shared Documents, and can open that OK with file explorer, but when I pick up that string from my vba using a filesystemobject, I just get path not found.

If I map a network drive letter, for that path, the code works OK, but the path isn't found if I use the full https://server etc.

My guess is that it's something to do with changing from http to https on the move  to SharePoint 2013
Anyone come across this before?

The actual code runs in Access 2013 and generates a full list of all the files in all the subfolders, and the ONLY problem now is that the filesystemobject.getfolder cannot find the path https://server/sites/Shared Documents  (but will if I map all that to drive W:)

Any clues or suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that `FileSystemObject` works with local file system and so mapping it to a drive name is a way to fool it. Are you saying it can't be fooled when you use `https` in the the mapping? You could try using `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` and parse the response to get the folders

Comment: Or `CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0")`

Comment: Thanks for this : I managed to get it working by a close examination of the drive mapping. I added '@SSLDavWWWRoot' at the right point, and hey presto!  - As I write the file list is being re-created. (Happy bunny)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has this, in my case, SharePoint 2013 needs
"@SSL\DavWWWRoot" added to the path, just before the "\Sites"
I found this by close examination of the path created by the drive mapping.